# Convert a floating point number to a localized string in C++

Tags: c++

How do I convert a floating point number in to a localized string in C++? For example- Suppose I have a floating point number 1.2 then in certain locales it should be converted to 1.2 and in others as 1,2.

Comment: You tagged 3 different C++ versions, how are they *all* relevant to this question? Do you want an answer for each version?

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Answer (score 3):

Construct a `std::locale` object with an empty string argument. This will use the locale that is configured for the system:

```
std::locale cpploc{""};
```

We can imbue this object into a character stream:

```
std::cout.imbue(cpploc);
```

Now, the output will have locale specific decimal point:

```
std::cout << 1.2; // either 1.2 or 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

Localized C++ programs shoud normally do this as the first thing:

```
std::locale loc("");
std::locale::global(loc);
```

Then all formatting should happen according to the user-preferred locale in all streams constructed after that point, but not in cin, cout and cerr (these are already constructed imbued withh the C locale). These streams need to be imbued with the user locale separately.

```
std.::cout.imbue(loc); // etc
```

Setting up the global locale changes not only formatting but character classification in is... functions and maybe a few other things.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Eeronika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58940495/10957435), if you are interested in simply converting it to a string, you have [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) as an option:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
//...
std::locale cpploc{""};
std::stringstream ss;

ss.imbue(cpploc);

ss << 1.2;

std::string asString = ss.str();
```

---

More on [`std::locale`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale)

Comment: Yes you do need `#include <string>`.  `std::stringstream` is just a specialization of `std::basic_stringstream` with `CharT==char`.  That means the return type of the `str` member function will have to be fully defined.  *However* that just means `std::basic_string` must be defined (possibly by #include from some internal header), it doesn't required `std::string` to be defined.

Comment: Of course, you could write `const auto asString = ss.str();` without needing the #include.

Comment: Good to know. I guess I missed in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) that it is returning a `std::basic_string`, not a `std::string`.

Comment: Anyway, I fixed it.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica `auto` solution isn't technically guaranteed to work as far as I know. Since it is member function of a template, it is probably defined inline in which case definition of `std::string` is needed by that definition and thus had to have been included. But in general, the caller is responsible for defining the return type.

Comment: @eerorika I *think* that it is not merely "probably" defined inline.  The whole of `std::basic_stringstream` has to be defined, and (ignoring `export`) that means it has to be defined.  I suppose `#include <stringstream>` could invoke some sort of export-like magic.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica To rephrase what I'm trying to say: If `std::string` is defined (either through direct or indirect inclusion), then you can write `std::string asString = ss.str()` or `auto asString = ss.str()` equally. In both cases you rely on that definition that was included. If `std::string` isn't defined (even through transitive inclusion), then you can do neither. In other words, `auto` changes nothing and has no effect on needing `#include <string>`.